# Heroku Custom Domain HTTPS Redirects with Google Domains

Tags: javascript, ssl, heroku, dns, hosting

I'm trying to set up a custom domain in a hobby dyno site I have with Heroku.

I've seen a few similar posts here, and have followed the consensus, but having some issues.

In Heroku, I have my custom domain set like this:  `www.allvintagesearch.com`

If I visit https://www.allvintagesearch.com/, the SSL cert works properly.

In Google Domains under DNS Custom Resource Records, I have a www CNAME pointing to the Heroku DNS.

Under Synthetic Records in Google Domains i set it as follows:

```
allvintagesearch.com → https://www.allvintagesearch.com
Temporary redirect (302), Do not forward path, Enable SSL
```

Now here's what's happening with each path:

```
https://www.allvintagesearch.com/  ===>  OK
http://allvintagesearch.com ==> redirects to https://www.allvintagesearch.com (OK)
http://www.allvintagesearch.com/  ===> Not secure
allvintagesearch.com ==> Not secure
```

Can someone help show me how to get all of the domains, either the www or the naked domain pointing to the secure version of the site?

Comment: You need to modify either your app or your Heroku webserver config to issue a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: yep you are very right about that, just installed this package and everything is working properly.  https://github.com/nodenica/node-heroku-ssl-redirect   thanks for the guidance!